# Getting ENOTFOUND error using Docker network

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have several containers being run and use a network with the `--net` flag.
This was all working fine, until recently, and now containers in the same network cannot talk to each other, and I am getting ENOTFOUND errors. Not really sure how to debug this, why would this happen?

I am on Docker version:

```
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
```

this problem is happening on both MacOS and Linux.

Comment: eh `docker ps` suggests that perhaps the containers that I think are up are not, fml2

Comment: So check the `docker logs <containerid>`  and see why it went down

Comment: Thanks Tarun, when I run docker logs, I see Error: EADDRNOTAVAIL - any idea why that might happen in a Docker network? Seems weird.

Comment: you are using `--net host` or `--net somenetwork`? If you using `somenetwork` then delete the network and try to recreate it again